# Invalid cell value - Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net, sql-server-2008

Making a .net site, taking over from someone who coded this.

the page is not opening, and says "Invalid cell value"

so am presuming its somewhere in the database, but i checked the database and cant see where it can be.

but any ideas on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like it could be an invalid spreadsheet on 1 of the database records.

You can check if this is the issue by removing the calls that create or process the excel file.

This I believe is the offending line, looking at the stack trace:

```
ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(String filePath, DataSet dataset) +644
```

Comment: An invalid spreadsheet stored as bytes in the database, is my prediction. The line I referenced above is the line you need to debug to start working out where the problem is.

Comment: its worked now!!! thanks but problem am getting now is opening the excel.. http://adhd.anytimeafter9.co.uk/_admin/adminworker.aspx?action=downloadstories&dest=story

Comment: any ideas about the excel issue

Comment: Corrupt spreadsheet? Try googling the exact message? Can you get a version of the spreadsheet before it errored?

Answer (score 2):

One of the reason of this error is NULL values.

Please check NULL in all your columns when extracting records from database.

```
For ex:- select ISNULL(Column1,'') as Column1 from Table1
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just encounter the same problem and nulls where part of the issue
Also discover that Unique-identifiers will bring this error too

I convert my Unique identifier as nvarchar on the SQL Statement generating the data table and this correct the issue for me

```
Convert(nvarchar(50), I.Guid) as Guid
```

Note that i found on another thread that int64 was causing the same issue, just be aware of the datatypes.